# Responsive layout and limit/trap content

Tags: css, html

I am trying to figure out how I can manage the following with the help of CSS.

I want the main website frame to be able to limit/trap all the content inside. Sicne I haven't coded anything yet I will show you with a drawing..

[image: how to avoid this]

As you can see on the example above, the red box "broke" the website border and instead of a responsive layout you now have a messed up one.. You basically have a fixed width for the red box which doesn't change even though the rest of the site is responsive and breaks the whole thing.

Is it possible to trap the red box inside the grey one? And do that generally with a div for example and not having to edit all the "red boxes" you might have?

Thank you!

Comment: All can change based on your actual HTML and CSS... maybe some simple like `width:100%` or more complicated with `position`

Answer (score 0):

Try any responsive layout framework  like Bootstrap [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

One of the example for sticky footer : [Sticky Footer](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Another example for Sticky Navbar and Footer : [StickyFooter-Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)

JsFiddle Example : [JsFiddleCode](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zaxt/)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It is my example's mistake mate. I didn't mean it was a sticky bar or something just a random object somewhere within the website. Something like the red bar here: http://jsfiddle.net/c2UyL/7/